# I'm trying to create an If Else statement in my crystal report and only the first line results are applying to all lines

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm comparing two formula fields, I've added a column to display the comments I'm getting for my end users to see.  But my formula results are the same for all lines instead of displaying the different comments but I'm not seeing what I have wrong with my formula

```
if {@Total EE Contribution} <= 5 and {@Total ER Contribution} > 5 then "Needs Review"
else 
if {@Total EE Contribution} >= 5 and ({@Total ER Contribution} <= 5) then "Match Aligns"
else
if {@Total EE Contribution} >= {@Total ER Contribution} then "May Need Additional Match"
else " "
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Display both formulas in the detail lines.
Then, review the logic in relation to these numbers to see where the problem is.

In other words, debug.